# Cannot edit Storage Rules in Firebase console

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-console

I am trying to edit the storage rules on Firebase to add read,write option but firebase just keeps on loading when I click on edit rules tab.
Can this be related to my setup? or anything wrong with firebase? TIA[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S4wz.png)

Answer (score 5):

*firebaser here*

There wass a known issue where some folks were not able to edit the security rules for Cloud Storage and Firestore in the Firebase console. This has been fixed now, so you should be able to load the rules into the console as usual again.

If that doesn't work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a moment to figure out, googled error message, landed here.

#### READ ONLY:

https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/databases/-default-/rules?authuser=0&hl=en&project=eth-london-separate

[image]

#### EDITABLE:

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/eth-london-separate/firestore/rules

*(of course the URL of the project will be slightly different for you)*