# Cant access firebase storage console rules 403

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security, firebase-console

I am having problems with firebase, i just recently started learning it. Im trying to setup my rules for firebase storage but it wont stop loading and i get error message 403 from the console. Full error message in JSON is:

{
"error": {

```
"code": 403, 
"message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "service": "firebaserules.googleapis.com",
      "consumer": "projects/300182265570"
    }
  }
]
```

}
}`

I've tried to google for answers but I'm not any wiser on what to do.

Sidenote, i also get some error message when i try to upload files to my storage from my app about "Bucket not being properply set up".

But I can't even access the rules on firebase.console for storage.

Cheers!

Comment: There is a known problem for some users in editing Firestore or Storage rules in the Firebase console at the moment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873546/cannot-edit-storage-rules-in-firebase-console/70873566#70873566 for the latest updates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot edit Storage Rules in Firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873546/cannot-edit-storage-rules-in-firebase-console)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks! Yes it does. Must be the case as you wrote! :)